# postgres round by variable decimal place

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a rounding length value by contract. I would like to round my data table by this value however I cannot find how to input it dynamically (ie changing 2 in the example below by 5). Is it possible?

Table trading.data18 structure
idcontract **integer**
close **double**

Table contracts structure
idcontract **integer**
rounding **double**

My static query so far

```
select ROUND(CAST(close AS numeric),2) from trading.data18 limit 10;
```

[image]

Comment: Can you share your table structures pls.

Comment: @Stefanov.sm I have added the request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `contracts.rounding` as a second argument of `round`.

```sql
select round(d.close, c.rounding::integer)::numeric
from trading.data18 as d
join contracts as c using(idcontract);
```

`using(idcontract)` is a shorthand for `on c.idcontract = d.idcontract`